# Web Api 2 - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

From Web Api Controller Action I'm trying to call another project's code to fetch data from DB basing on passed request. But I'm getting this error when doing that:

**CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**

I'm getting the issue when invoking this code:

```
[Route("api/GetProducts")]
    [HttpGet]
    public GetProductsResponse GetProducts([FromUri]GetProductsRequest keyRequest)
    {
        var shop = new Shop(); // this is being places in my other project where I have EF code first

        return shop.GetProducts(keyRequest);
    }
```

The database connection is being established in the external project (not in the Web Api) and all the operations are being performed there as well.

I was googling a lot, but there's not so much info regarding the issue.

Many thanks in advance for some help!

I expect the query result to be sent from my method of external project.

Comment: Please include your code!

Comment: Code included, but it won't tell you much more. And I'm not able to post the GetProducts(keyRequest) method, as this is private company code.

Comment: Check your connection string. Seems like its datasource is 'master' (reserved for internal SQL Server system information). Did you intend on pointing to a different database on that SQL Server instance?

Comment: The connection string has the DataSource set to right DB, I checked that. But the connection string is defined in this external project. Should I also put one in Web Api one?

Comment: Yes, give that a try. Sounds like your "external" project is just a separate project/assembly in your solution in which case your main project would need its own connection setup.

Comment: This sounds like your auto-migrating and you don't actually have this database setup. The database user you're using doesn't have CREATE DATABASE privileges (as well it shouldn't), but EF is trying to create the database. You should ensure that the database exists first, and go ahead and create all tables. You should also just get rid of any auto-migration stuff. Schema migrations should be applied in the release pipeline, not on app start.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help [jcruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3169688/jcruz)! I managed to solve the issue by putting in my Web API 2 project an EF connection string. Thanks!